# How do I change the background colour of two/more different fieldsets using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have two field sets on float-left next to each other, I would like each of them to have a different background colour.
Obviously just changing the background  colour of the fieldset changes all of them to the same colour, this is not what I want, as you can see I have assigned each fieldset with a name but I can't get the background colours to be different:

In CSS:

```
    fieldset{
background-color: aquamarine;
border: none;
float: left;
font-style: italic;
```

In HTML:

```
     </head>
    <h1 span class="white">Info Day</span> <span class="blue">Registration</span></h1>
<body>
    <form name="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        <fieldset name="fieldset1">
        <legend>Step 1</legend>
        How many people will be attending?
            <select name = step1 id="step1" onchange="showField()">
            <option value="0">Please Choose</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        <br>
        <div id="divName"></div>
        <img id="check" src="check.png">
        </fieldset> 
    </form>

  <form name="form2" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        <fieldset name= "fieldset2">
        <legend>Step 2</legend>
            Would you like your company name on your badges?<br>
            <input type="radio">Yes<input type="radio">No
        <br>
        <div id="company"></div>
        Will anyone in your group require special accommodations?<br>
       (if yes) Please explain below:<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Yes" value="Yes">Yes<input type="radio" name="No" value="No">No
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to define classes instead of names, then style those CSS classes. Here's a running example:

```css
.fieldset1 {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.fieldset2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1 span class="white">Info Day</span> <span class="blue">Registration</span></h1>

<body>
  <form name="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <fieldset class="fieldset1">
      <legend>Step 1</legend>
      How many people will be attending?
      <select name=s tep1 id="step1" onchange="showField()">
        <option value="0">Please Choose</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <div id="divName"></div>
      <img id="check" src="check.png">
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <form name="form2" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <fieldset class="fieldset2">
      <legend>Step 2</legend>
      Would you like your company name on your badges?
      <br>
      <input type="radio">Yes
      <input type="radio">No
      <br>
      <div id="company"></div>
      Will anyone in your group require special accommodations?
      <br>(if yes) Please explain below:
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="Yes" value="Yes">Yes
      <input type="radio" name="No" value="No">No
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: It's not recommended to use IDs for CSS selectors due to their narrow specificity. https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-ids-in-selectors

Comment: @JonUleis ok I changed the answer to use classes instead

Answer (score 1):

```
fieldset[name=fieldset1]{
   background-color: color;
}

fieldset[name=fieldset2]{
    background-color: color2;
}
```

Comment: Aren't you missing quote marks? Otherwise yours is the most straightforward answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `class` or `id` attributes for assigning CSS rules: `<fieldset class="fieldset1">` or `<fieldset id="fieldset1">` instead of `<fieldset name="fieldset1">`

Then in the CSS you can use this for classes:

```
.fieldset1 { 
  ...
}
```

or this for IDs:

```
#fieldset1 { 
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why not use the `name` attribute?

Comment: Yes it does: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBKYqP. You can use any attribute as a selector.